# Website works fine for me but others are getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I have the following Apache config file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect all calls to non-WWW HTTPS which works for me, the website is loading fine and all redirects are working as intended. When I however test the website speed with different speed testing tools such as Googles own tool or any proxy they simply return `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. I even asked a few people to try the website and they are also getting the same error.

Does someone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Your redirect directives are overly complex, however, there's nothing here that suggests why 3rd parties are seeing a redirect loop when you are not. Are they connecting to the same site? Is your site private to your network?! If you examine the network traffic when _you_ access the site; what do you see - any redirects at all?

Comment: @MrWhite I am seeing the error on my phone, it seems to be something related to Laravel since I removed all redirect code from the config file and put it in my .htaccess in Laravel and the same error came up.

Comment: It may be to do with Laravel - although moving the redirect code from the server config to `.htaccess` does not prove this? Moving the redirect code to `.htaccess` shouldn't make any difference with regards to this problem? If you are getting a redirect loop on some devices then it would seem those devices are getting a different response from your server? Or one or other are seeing a cached response? When connecting via your phone, are you connecting via the same network? Or mobile network?

Comment: @MrWhite When I connect via my phone its via mobile network, only my computer seems to have some cached version that works somehow.